# change flat json to list json in React

Tags: reactjs

i got api in https://api.exchangerate.host/latest, if you see the rates, i wanna change from

```
rates :{"start": 1,...., "end": 20}
```

into

```
rates:[{"start": 1},..,{"end":20}]
```

The reason because i cannot map it using

```
rates.map(item=> <li>item.key | item.val</li>);
```

or using

```
render(){
    var {isLoaded, items} = this.state;
    

    if(!isLoaded){
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }else{
      const results = Object.entries(items.rates).map(el => ({"key":[el[0]], "value": el[1]}))
    
    // console.log(results);
      return(
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
              <ul>
                {results.map(item => <li key={item["key"]}> {item["key"]} : {item["value"]} </li>)}
              </ul>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
  } 
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: `Object.keys` returns only keys (exactly what the name says) You need `rates[key]` to get the value

Comment: @Andrew you mean like this?  {JSON.parse(rates).map(item => <li>item.key</li>)}

Comment: @mousetail is it like this? Object.keys(rates).map(el => results.push({el:rates[el]}));

Comment: Yes, but in that case it will be tricky to access the key in the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Object.entries(), like so:

```
const data = { start: 1, end: 20 }
const res = Object.entries(data).map(el => ({[el[0]]: el[1]}))
console.log(res) // returns [ { start: 1 }, { end: 20 } ]
```

If need be you can stringify the return value to format as JSON

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(res)) // returns [{"start":1},{"end":20}]
```